# Mutating outer variables inside React Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to create a form (with redux-form) which contains a variable number of checkboxes.

However, those checkboxes are passed down to the component via props. Therefore I am unable to use them in the fields part of the exportation:

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'formCheckBoxes',
    fields: fields,
    validate
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(FilterComponent);
```

Please help me, I have spent hours on this issue.

Comment: You should check Deep Form on Redux Form site: http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/examples/deep?_k=ixmfya There is example for looping fields :)

Comment: you can use connect from 'react-redux' npm module and do as following:
export default connect(state => ({
 fields: state. fields,
}), actions)(FilterComponent);

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/api/reduxForm):

> **IMPORTANT: All of these configuration options may be passed into reduxForm() at "design time" or passed in as props to your component at runtime.**

This means that `fields` can be a prop to your decorated component.

```
FilterComponent = reduxForm({
  form: 'formCheckboxes',
  validate
})(FilterComponent)
```

Then later, in your container where you have the `fields`:

```
<FilterComponent fields={myFields}/>
```

Comment: Thanks Erik, awesome work. Can you please tell me how to do this in redux-form v6? Thanks